# Code keeps crashing (Week 4.2 has stopped working

Tags: c, arrays, file, fgets

I have a program that has to get the longest sentence from a file.
To achieve this, I am putting the first sentence in an array and then comparing future sentences to the currently largest sentence's size.

However the act of comparing both array's eludes me.
The array's current_sentence and longest_sentence are both 80 characters long, but I wish to know which actually contains the longest sentence (which can be up to 80 characters long).

I have already attempted many different solutions (through google, most of which were stackoverflow results) but every time I make an attempt the returned value is the first sentence in the file, which makes me believe that either the check itself fails entirely, or the length of both array's is returned as 80.

These attempts include (but are not limited to):

```
if((sizeof(current_sentence) / sizeof(char)) < (sizeof(longest_sentence) / sizeof(char))

if(sizeof(current_sentence) / sizeof(current_sentence[0])) < (sizeof(longest_sentence) / sizeof(longest_sentence[0]))
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *langste_regel(char *);

int main(void) {
    /*
     * stdout and stderr required for proper output
     */
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    char *s = langste_regel("vb1.txt");
    if(s != NULL) {
        printf("\nde langste regel is: %s\n", s);
        free(s);
    }

    return 0;
}

char *langste_regel(char *filename) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Kan bestand niet %s openen", filename);
    }

    char current_sentence[80];
    int len = 2;
    char *longest_sentence = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);

    fgets(longest_sentence, 80, file);

    while(fgets(current_sentence, 80, file)) {
        if(sizeof(current_sentence) < sizeof(longest_sentence)) {
            strncpy(longest_sentence, current_sentence, 80);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    return longest_sentence;
}
```

Comment: Use `strlen()` not `sizeof`.  `sizeof` is an operator that evaluates to the size of the variable.  `strlen()` is a function that returns the length of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `strlen()` to get length of the line(s), not `sizeof` which returns the number of bytes the objects occupy.

Change

```
    if(sizeof(current_sentence) < sizeof(longest_sentence)) {
```

to

```
    if(strlen(current_sentence) < strlen(longest_sentence)) {
```

Another problem I see is that you are allocating only 2 bytes but reading upto 80 bytes here:

```
  char *longest_sentence = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);

  fgets(longest_sentence, 80, file);
```

Comment: Yes I learned that I needed to allocate the array so I could return it's value (otherwise I would get a local variable error). I don't know entirely how the len variable works in this scenarion. I could change the 2 to 80 but then it wouldn't be dynamic anymore(?). Or do I set it to 80 and then it automatically increases from there?

Comment: PS: I just tested this and it works, including the allocation of 80 bytes. It turns out my comparison was also wrong and I needed `strlen(current_sentence) > strlen(longest_sentence)` instead of `strlen(current_sentence) < strlen(longest_sentence)`. Thank you for your help and I will mark your answer as accepted ASAP.

Comment: *I could change the 2 to 80 but then it wouldn't be dynamic anymore(?)* why not? If you don't know the actual length of the line(s) and not sure if they won't exceed then you'll need to read char by char and use `realloc` to increase memory.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
sizeof(current_sentence)
```

isn't doing what you think.  To find the length of a null terminated string, use

```
strlen(current_sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code.

> ```
>   file = fopen(filename, "r");
>
>    if(file == NULL) {
>        fprintf(stderr, "Kan bestand niet %s openen", filename);
>    }
> ```

You check if the `fopen()` call is unsuccessful, but then you just move on and use the `file` pointer anyway. You should return an error indication to the caller.

---

> ```
>   char current_sentence[80];
>   int len = 2;
>   char *longest_sentence = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
>
>   fgets(longest_sentence, 80, file);
> ```

You allocate 2 bytes to `longest_sentence` and then you try to read as much as 80 bytes into the buffer. You should allocate 80 bytes.

If you meant to dynamically grow the buffer as needed, you need a much more elaborate solution. You need to:

- Try to allocate 80 bytes.
- Try to read 80 bytes.
- Check if the string ends with a newline (`\n`).
- If not, try to `realloc()` the buffer to a larger size.
- Continue reading and re-allocating until

  - a newline has been found, or
  - you've reached end-of-file, or
  - a read error occurs, or
  - the re-allocation fails, or
  - you reach a pre-defined max length.

You also don't check if the string was read successfully. The `fgets()` function will return `NULL` on end-of-file or if a read error has occurred. You should return an error indicator to the caller. Eg:

```
if (!fgets(longest_sentence, 80, file)) {
  free (longest_sentence);
  return NULL:
}
```

---

> ```
>   while(fgets(current_sentence, 80, file)) {
>       if(sizeof(current_sentence) < sizeof(longest_sentence)) {
>           strncpy(longest_sentence, current_sentence, 80);
>       }
>   }
> ```

The result of the `sizeof` operator is the size of the *type* of the operand, not the length of the strings. You should use `strlen()` (and reverse the comparison, as you have noted elsewhere).

```
while(fgets(current_sentence, 80, file)) {
    if(strlen(current_sentence) > strlen(longest_sentence)) {
        strncpy(longest_sentence, current_sentence, 80);
    }
}
```

The use of `strncpy()` is usually questionable. The call above will *always* write 80 bytes, regardless of the length of `current_sentence`. In general, it will *not* zero-terminate the output string if no zero is found within the first 80 bytes of the input string. It will in *this* case however, because `fgets()` guarantees that there is a zero byte within those 80 characters.

A simple `strcpy()` would be more straightforward here (in my opinion).